# How portable is it to load a symbol table structure from a shared/dynamic library?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

It seems to work fine on windows and linux to use either GetProcAddress() or dlsym() to return a structure populated with function pointers to use from a dynamic library.

...but, there seem to be a huge number of people asking questions and complaining about casting void * pointers to function pointers, and talking about using dlfunc, when this relatively simple approach seems to work just fine.

So, is there any particular reason why you wouldn't want to do this?

Is code like this not portable for some reason?

I realize that this approach only works for sharing explicitly named functions and bound functions, but for loading a plugin thats fine as far as I'm concerned...?

header.h:

```
/* C++ safety & windows support */
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #if _WIN32 || _WIN64
    #define __EXT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define __EXT extern "C"
  #endif
#else
  #if _WIN32 || _WIN64
    #define __EXT __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define __EXT extern
  #endif
#endif

struct a_sym_table {
  int (* action) (int argc, char *argv[]);
};

__EXT struct a_sym_table liba_symbols;
```

source.c:

```
int perform_action_lib_a(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rtn = perform_action_lib_b() + perform_action_lib_c();
  return(rtn);
}

struct a_sym_table liba_symbols = {
  &perform_action_lib_a
};
```

Edit: Just for clarity, *obviously* the code to *load the symbol* will be different on different platforms, but this approach allows the *shared library* to be portable to different platforms without change.

That's what I'm talking about when I ask, is there a reason why you wouldn't do this?

What I want to know is if there's some good reason not to structure your *shared libraries* like this for *portabilities* sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing data from a shared library. This is what dlsym() is for. Dynamic linkers should be able to handle function pointers passing library boundaries just fine. At least on unix-like systems. I don't know about Windows, but I can imagine lots of things breaking if some types of pointers worked and others didn't.

When it comes to portability, you're already limited to systems that either have the stuff you already have behind "#if _WIN32 || _WIN64" or implement dlsym. This should already hint that what you're doing has been made to work by testing and not following some strict standard document. So you're portable to "whatever this works on".

Comment: IIRC, `dlfcn.h` is part of POSIX (POSIX.1-2001), so it should be pretty portable. Even to some more recent Windows.

Comment: The real issue is that standards compliant C forbids casting between a void * and a function pointer; one *some* systems, like linux, that works, but on others it doesn't (BSD) and you have to use dlfcn instead. There are a huge number of threads around on this issue. -- I'm just trying to minimize the number of #if's I have to use this way.

Comment: But you're not casting between void and a function pointers. You're casting between a void and a struct pointers. The struct contains a function pointer. At least that's what you show in the example code.

Comment: I know, thats what I'm talking about. Casting void * to function pointers like *you're* talking about isnt portable.

Comment: I don't see where I'm talking about that? The concern about function pointers passing shared library boundaries is valid and I thought that was what you were worried about. At least two systems 15 years ago didn't have it working in some cases because of lazy binding. But it has nothing to do with casting void * to a function pointer.